# AutoMapper: Unflattening to constructor

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's say I have the following classes

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar First { get; }

    public Bar Second { get; }

    public Foo(Bar first, Bar second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class FooDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to map `FooDto` to `Foo`. I've read about [Reverse Mapping and Unflattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening) so I setup my confoguration like so:

```
IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
        .ReverseMap();
}).CreateMapper();
```

Unfortunately this fails with

> System.ArgumentException : Test.AutoMapper.Foo needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.

How can I configure AutoMapper to use the `Foo` constructor without manually mapping all constructor parameters? (In my actual code, the types have more properties)

Comment: How can it map from `FooDto` to `Foo` (which is implied by ReverseMap)? It should get 2 `Bar` instances to pass to constructor, but where?

Comment: @Evk You can check that it works by removing the `Foo` constructor and making the properties mutable. AutoMapper will automatically create 2 `Bar` instances by unflattening `FirstName` and `SecondName`. It just doesn't manage to call the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the conversion explicitly, cause the names of the constructor arguments and property names differ. For further informations take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Construction).

[Here is a running example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2hJ41F):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.CreateMap<FooDto, Foo>()
            .ForCtorParam("first", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForCtorParam("second", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SecondName));
        config.CreateMap<string, Bar>().ConvertUsing(value => new Bar() { Name = value });
    });

    var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
    var dto = new FooDto() { FirstName = "Hello", SecondName = "World" };

    var foo = mapper.Map<Foo>(dto);

    Console.WriteLine(foo.First.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Second.Name);
}
```